# Проводной интернет + GPRS на одной машине

Tags: сеть, администрирование

Здравствуйте.

Есть корпоративный интернет через proxy с закрытыми сайтами и портами. В связи с кризисом на основной работе хочу немного пофрилансить в рабочее время и для этого необходим постоянный коннект.

Задача: нужно не отключая корпоративый интернет, подключить GPSR и настроить выход скажем firefox и некоторых других программ в инет через него,  а остальные: почта, IE и т.д. будут ходить через корпоративный.

Сисадмин из меня так себе. Поэтому нужен совет как это все дело организовать...

Answer (score 1):

Если комп хороший, проще всего использовать виртуалку для работы. Если комп не такой хороший, то можно использовать виртуалку с линуксом или FreeBSD, на которую поставить прокси-сервер, который затем надо прописать в настройках тех программ.

В обоих случаях GPRS-модем надо будет пробросить в виртуалку.

Answer (score -1):

wifi direct (в смартфоне) + WiFi адаптер(USB адаптер для компа или ноута от 400 руб.)

```
 меня только это спасает
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]